# Classic ASP - Get the exact error while invoking a registered dll

Tags: dll, asp-classic, regsvr32

I am working on an ASP applicaiton that uses a registered dll.It works fine in IIS 6.

Now we are trying to host the ASP site on IIS7.5 , windows 2008 R2 64 bit OS.

I registered the dll in the Windows 2008 64 bit machine using regsvr32.exe in SysWOW64 folder and it is registered successfully. I enabled 32 bit applications in the application pool which is used.

When I invoke the dll, the ASP code fails and a message is shown in IE saying " Internet explorer cannot display the webpage "

In IIS setttings, I set Send errors to Browser as True.

In IE, under Advance tab, I unchecked "Show user friendly HTTP error messages"

But still I could not see the actual error that is thrown while calling the dll.

I also tried in ASP page. The Err number is 0.

```
On Error Resume Next

Set download = Server.CreateObject("FunctionUpload.File")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 Response.Write Err.Description
 Err.Clear
 End if
```

ASP code fails and shows IE cannot display the webpage after this line.

```
download.ToName filename
```

I want to know the exact error that occurs here.How to get the exact error message that occurs while calling the dll?

Thanks
Ashok

Comment: Have you checked the windows system logs?  Big ones like this tend to turn up in there.

Comment: Step 1: remove the on error resume next that line should be in production code and not in debugging code. Step 2: check the IIS log for the exact error message. Step 3: check for security related issues, try setting the network service account plus the authenticated user account (in dev environment of-course) modify right to your drives to discover if the prob. is security related,

Comment: Have you configured your error pages in IIS manager, you need to do that in addition to setting "send errors to browser" to true.  see this - http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: Hi, I chekced event viewer. I could not see any information at the time when I get this error. I configured error pages (send error to browser is True. In Error pages, Edit Features and settings, enabled Detailed error). I still could not get the error message. Not sure what happens in the line download.ToName filename.  IE says page cannot be displayed. This happends only when I invoke this dll and call the method. Other pages work fine. any help would be appreciated.